# How would I refresh this panel

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a kind of digital clock which you can activate by using enter to kind of refresh the clock display, for that I use this method:

```
private static void GUI(String time, int action){
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(time);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame enterMessage = new JFrame("Tester");
    if (action == 1){

        enterMessage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        enterMessage.setSize(190, 80);
        enterMessage.setVisible(true);

        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        panel.add(textLabel);

        enterMessage.add(panel);
    }else {
        System.out.printf("Refresh");
        panel.revalidate();
        enterMessage.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        enterMessage.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

This method gets called twice in the program code: one time to make the GUI upon opening the program and everytime an enterpress is detected to refresh it. I searched on internet how to refresh a `JPanel` and I found that you needed to use `revalidate();` and then `repaint();` but it does not refresh the time displayed by the panel. How would I refresh it?

ps:the time is passed from the main as a string and everytime an enterpress is detected gets overwritten and passed

Comment: Can you provide it as an asnwer so i can thick you and you get credit

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT_ALL_UPPER`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Does the functionality of the code depend on that? I just lerned it this way and I like it if it does not interfear with the functionality I will keep doing it like this

Comment: _I just lerned it this way and I like it if it does not interfear with the functionality I will keep doing it like this_ It interferes with our ability to read the code. The syntax-highlighter on this site isn't happy either with your own convention

Comment: `I just lerned it this way` I doubt it. I have never seen a text book or example code posted in any forum on the web site using your style. Learn by example and don't make up your own conventions. When you post your `MCVE` or `SSCCE` make sure the code follows the proper naming conventions.

Comment: I have an informatics teacher which teaches me, he told me it like that!

Comment: *"..he told me it like that!"*  Now's your chance to explain to him the *correct* way to do it.  But don't expect us to wade through the code, guessing which is an attribute, and which a class.

Comment: Allright I just don't get why it's wrong, All my programs worked till now and It had nothing to do with upper case letters

Comment: Of course it works. We are not saying it won't work. It is just very confusing if you do not follow the conventions that everybody in the industry is using. i CaN wRiTe coMMenTs LiKE thIs and you will still be able to read them. It is just much more effort compared to the same comment using the normal casing

Answer (score 2):

Follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Don't keep adding the label to the panel. Just use the setText(...) method of JLabel to change the text being displayed.

Edit:

An example of a `SSCCE` that shows you how to use the `setText(...)` method:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTime extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel timeLabel;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        add( timeLabel );

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e.getSource());
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTime");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TimerTime() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i use this method, and how?

Comment: You call the setText() method by using `textLabel.setText(time);`

Comment: If you see "refresh" displaying at the correct time and you set the text to the label, then the text on the label will update. If it does not update then you don't have a reference to the label that is displayed on the GUI. We can't help you unless you post a proper `MVCE" or `SSCCE` like you have already been asked to do.

Comment: Did you read the links provided in the comment section to your question?

Comment: yep but I am not a native english speaker and I don't fully understand

Comment: *"I don't know what that is."*  That's why I linked to a description. *"I don't fully understand"* So ***ask** rather than ignore the comment.  But be specific about what you do not understand, I don't intend to explain it word by word (which I thought was already well achieved in either of those documents.

Comment: I don't understand ow to change my code that I have into good code for you. I also don't know what lines to put in and which not

Comment: @CoderGuy, `I don't understand how to change my code` - neither do we. A few lines of code does not give us the context of how the code is used. That is why you need to post a proper `SSCCE` that demonstrates what you are doing. Get rid of code not directly related to the problem. I posted a SSCCE show how you can do this with minimal code. This is how you learn to simplify a problem and make it easier to debug.